# Drupal 7 appending class in uc attribute option radio button

Tags: hooks, ubercart

I have this code inside **mymodule_form_alter**:

```
     foreach ($form['attributes'] as $att) {
        foreach ($att['#options'] as $option => $value) {
  // Get the name of the option without the price or price adjustment -> string before coma
            $optionName = explode(",", $att['#options'][$option], 2)[0];
            if (strpos($optionName, '+') !== false) {
                $att['#options'][$option]['#attributes'][] = array('class' => array('my_class'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately

> $att['#options'][$option]['#attributes'][] = array('class' =>
>   array('my_class'));

Displays unexpected error, I tried different syntax but no success. Any help much appreciated

> Update 27/09/2017

I tried to do this by using **after_build** I get no errors but it isn't working

```
// Inside hook_form_alter
 $form['attributes']['#after_build'][] = 'addToCartFormEditQuantity_after_build';

 function addToCartFormEditQuantity_after_build(&$element, &$form_state)
{
    // Each renderable radio element.
    foreach ($element as $attribute) {
        foreach (element_children($attribute) as $option) {
            var_dump($attribute[$option]);
      // Get the name of the option without the price or price adjustment -> string before coma
            $optionName = explode(",", $attribute['#options'][$option], 2)[0];
            if (strpos($optionName, '+') !== false) {
                $attribute[$option]['#atrributes']['class'] .= 'single-double';
            }
        }
    }

    return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I wanted  inside **theme_uc_attribute_add_to_cart** by using:

```
foreach (element_children($form) as $aid) {
     foreach (element_children($form[$aid]) as $option) {

        $form[$aid][$option]['#prefix'] = '<div class="row single-double">';
        $form[$aid][$option]['#suffix'] = '</div>';

      }
    }
```

But I really don't want to mess with uc_attribute.theme.inc is there any other way?